# Is there a way to decompress a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, encryption, compression

I have a js where the contents look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 02 Dec 2011 03:40:37 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Last-Modified: Fri, 12 Jun 2011 02:36:40 GMT
ETag: "7812e-1228-4a5df9820de00"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 2009
```

and then a wall of:

```
00000000:  5e  01  00  00  02  08  00  00  e0  ff  d2  d4  36  12  2e  00  ^...........6...
```

Since there is mention of `gzip`, I assume this is a compressed javascript file?

Or is this some sort of encryption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gzip -cd` on the data should be sufficient to decompress it.

The compression used is the same as [`zlib`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib) in case you want an API to decompress your data.

Comment: Thanks, I don't actually develop javascript. Is there an application that can do this?

Comment: Download the JavaScript using something like `wget(1)`, `curl(1)`, `GET(1)`, etc: `wget http://servername/path/to/source.js`. Heck, it might decompress it for you. If it isn't decompressed, then run `gzip -cd source.js > uncompressed_source.js`.

Answer (score 2):

It is a gzip compressed javascript file. You may be able to view it using **[Firebug extension](http://getfirebug.com/)** in Firefox.